# change the content of div with another div- jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**My Requirement:**
        I have three different `<div>`s. when user click the first link, first `<div>` data should be display. when click the second link, display second `<div>`data at the position of first `<div>`.

**code:**

```
<div id="firstdiv" >
//first div data
</div>

<div id="seconddiv">
//second div data
</div>

<div id="lastdiv">
//last div data
</div>

<ul class="footer_links">
        <li><a href="#" id="firstlink"></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="secondlink"></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="lastlink"></li>
</ul>
```

Here when user click the `firstlink` need to display the `fistdiv` data and when user click the `secondlink` need to display `seconddiv` data at position of `firstdiv`.

for this i have done jQuery, but it is not proper way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#firstdiv").replaceWith($('#seconddiv'));
    $('#seconddiv').attr('id', 'firstdiv');
});
```

Here i have done `firstdiv` replacing with `seconddiv` and changing the id to `firstdiv`.
It displaying data at position of first `<div>`. But display forward only. Not as backward. Because here I am replacing `firstdiv` with `seconddiv`. So its not proper way. Can any one tell this. How can I do this forward and backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change your html to the following:

```
<div id="firstdiv" class="datadiv">
//first div data
</div>

<div id="seconddiv" class="datadiv">
//second div data
</div>

<div id="lastdiv" class="datadiv">
//last div data
</div>

<ul class="footer_links">
    <li><a href="#firstdiv" id="firstlink" class="link">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#seconddiv" id="secondlink" class="link">second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lastdiv" id="lastlink" class="link">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

you can use the following jquery:

```
var divs = $('.datadiv');
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    divs.hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3yy/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="firstdiv" class="myDiv" style="display:none;" >
//first div data
</div>

<div id="seconddiv" class="myDiv" style="display:none;" >
//first div data
</div>

<div id="lastdiv" class="myDiv" style="display:none;" >
//last div data
</div>

<ul class="footer_links">
        <li><a href="#" id="firstlink" data-div="firtstdiv"></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="secondlink" data-div="seconddiv"></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="lastlink" data-div="lastdiv"></li>
</ul>
```

in javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".footer_link a")click(function(e){
        $(".myDiv").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).data("div")).show();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

});
```